# SELinux with docker and traefik

Tags: docker, fedora, selinux

I have a SELinux security problem on /run/docker.sock using traefik in docker. 
`docker ps` works correctly, it's only a problem with traefik needing to map volume /var/run/docker.sock

Here is what I tried:

```
 git clone https://github.com/jamct/traefik-example.git
 cd traefik-example/04_config_files
 sudo setenforce 0
 docker-compose up
 #it works
 sudo setenforce 1
 docker-compose up
 # it fails

$ ls  -lsZ /run/docker.sock
0 srw-rw-rw-. 1 root docker system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c134,c237 0  4 mars  11:38 /run/docker.sock
```

I have got this error log

```
traefik_1  | time="2020-03-04T15:46:16Z" level=error msg="Provider connection error Got permission    denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied, retrying in 4.506218855s" providerName=docker
```

and the log in permissive mod in /var/log/audit/audit.log:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1583336776.607:1931): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=16969 comm="traefik" path="/run/docker.sock" scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c134,c237 tcontext=system_u:system_r:container_runtime_t:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
```

the docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.0
    command: --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw
      - ./traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
      - ./dynamic.yml:/etc/traefik/dynamic/traefik.yml
  web1:
    image: nginx:alpine
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.web1.rule=Host(`web1.localhost`)
  web2:
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.web2.rule=Host(`web2.localhost`) || ( Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/web2`) )
      - traefik.http.routers.web2.middlewares=demo-whitelist@file
```

Is there a clean way to make traefik work with selinux enabled? Is there a "chcon" CLI that I can use on /run/docker.sock file?

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1495053

Comment: @Bert hank you, it really helped, I formulated my answer based on this link. I didn't found this link in my search..

Answer (score 2):

**Edit and Disclaimer**: this solution is not the recommended one since it breaks security rules on docker, The solutions are here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089023/var-run-docker-sock-unaccessible-in-container-running-on-centos-7/30368817#30368817

Thanks to the bug report of redhat given by @Bert I could get a solution:

### Why SELinux prevent access to /run/docker.sock in redhat configuration (fedora, centos)

[Bug 1495053 - SELinux is preventing traefik from 'connectto'](http://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1495053%20%E2%80%93) 
This bug report is classed as "not a bug" for the folowing reason:

> You are trying to connect a confined domain to the docker socket. 
>   There is no sense in doing this, since the ability to talk to the
>   docker socket allows you full control over the host.  Either this is a
>   very serious breakout of your container, or you should be running a
>   privileged container.  SELinux is doing exactly what it should do in
>   blocking access to the docker socket.

So i shouldn't change access to docker.sock as it would be the same as disabling selinux.
Instead, I could run in a "privileged" container.

### Solution

I just changed the docker-compose.yml file to run in provilieged mode (the same mode can be obtained in other docker launchers).

Here is the working docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.1.6
    command: --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:rw
      - ./traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
      - ./dynamic.yml:/etc/traefik/dynamic/traefik.yml
  web1:
    image: nginx:alpine
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.web1.rule=Host(`web1.localhost`)  ||  PathPrefix(`/web1`) 
  web2:
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.web2.rule=Host(`web2.localhost`) || ( Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/web2`) )
      - traefik.http.routers.web2.middlewares=demo-whitelist@file
```

The important line is  **privileged: true** in the traefik container.

With **privileged: true** and selinux enabled, it works, if i change back to `privileged: false`, I get back the error log, what is expected.

Comment: also related https://github.com/containous/traefik-library-image/issues/38